# Why this "for type-test pattern" fails?

Tags: f#, type-conversion, pattern-matching

I'm currently extracting information about method from type here is the relevant part of my current code (which works correctly) :

```
let ctorFlags = BindingFlags.NonPublic ||| BindingFlags.Public ||| BindingFlags.Instance ||| BindingFlags.Static
let methodFlags = BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly ||| ctorFlags

[
    for t in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes() do
        for c in t.GetConstructors ctorFlags -> c :> MethodBase
        for m in t.GetMethods methodFlags -> m :> MethodBase
]
|> printfn "%A"
```

Then I wanted to make a small change using the fact that the [syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233182.aspx) is `for pattern in expr`. and that [type test pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547125.aspx#Anchor_15) match if given input is a match to (or **a derived type of**) given type ; so I wrote this :

```
// same flags as before
[
    for t in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes() do
        for :? MethodBase as m in t.GetConstructors ctorFlags -> m
        for :? MethodBase as m in t.GetMethods methodFlags -> m
]
|> printfn "%A"
```

And that gives me an error on `GetConstructors` line (translated to English by me)

> Incompatibility in type constraint. type `MethodBase` isn't compatible with type `ConstructorInfo`.

After a double-check [ConstructorInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.constructorinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) derives from MethodBase (and same for [MethodInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)).

*Note : if I use a flexible type (`#MethodBase`) instead ; the pattern works but for constructors `m` has type `RuntimeConstructorInfo` and for methods `m` hash type `RuntimeMethodInfo` (what is the expected behaviour using flexible type). I obviously tested them separately as having a list of two different types isn't allowed.*

So question is : Why did I missed/misunderstood ?

Comment: If you use :> instead of ?>, does that solve your problem?

Comment: @Foole I don't use ?> (not even sure it exists) and in case you meant replacing :? with :> that can't be done in a pattern so only place where I can use :> would be in the "body" of the for and that's exactly what i've done in my initial code. If you didn't mean that, then I didn't understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler reports the error when you try to use the `:?` pattern to cast to a supertype from a subtype (an *upcast*) which is a cast that can never fail. It is worth noting that you get exactly the same error when you use the `:?` pattern for an upcast anywhere else:

```
match System.Random() with
| :? obj as o -> o
```

I think the `:?` pattern has mainly been intended for safe downcasts (the situation when the pattern matching can fail). For example:

```
match box 1 with
| :? string as s -> "string"
| :? int as n -> "int"
```

The compiler checks whether the type you're casting to (here `string` and `int`) is a valid subtype of the type used in the parameter (here `object`).

Converting `string` to `object` (or `ConstructorInfo` to `MethodBase`) would also be valid, but for a different reason - and the compiler apparently only does the more common kind of check.

Your attempt to use `:?` definitely makes a lot of sense to me - and I think the check in the compiler could be relaxed to allow this. You can [post this as a suggestion to the F# user voice](https://fslang.uservoice.com/).

Comment: So basically that's an error in the documentation, no ? it states clearly that a derived type input is a match where it seems that's the opposite : derived type are allowed only for the case not the input part.

Comment: I disagree with the latest paragraph. `for :? MethodBase as m in t.GetConstructors ctorFlags -> m` should really be `for m in t.GetConstructors ctorFlags -> m :> MethodBase`; these are different use cases: the former may not match all elements in the list, the latter is due to F# not having implicit upcasts. IMO the semantics of potentially filtering should be clearly separated from upcasting.